# Why Openssl C API get different thumbprint result with openssl s_client command line

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I am using openssl API to get server's certificate thumbprint information as below code.

```
X509 *cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
if (!X509_digest(cert, fprint_type, fprint, &fprint_size))

for (j=0; j<fprint_size; ++j) BIO_printf(outbio, "%02x ", fprint[j]);
BIO_printf(outbio,"\n");
```

At the same time, I use command line to get fingerprint as below:

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout -in /dev/stdin
```

Then I found a **strange** behavior, In some web site, API print the same thumbprint same as command line,  but in some web sites, I found something strange.

- API will print different thumbprint value from command line. and I use browser to view web site's certificate, and I find that command line's fingerprint value is same as browser show.
- When API show different thumbprint from command line, I found other things is same, **Subject, Issuer**, it is only thumbprint different.

Is something wrong that I do not call API correctly? Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you get the same certificate? Please provide examples so that one can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, I am behind a proxy, And I found that I could not get the same result is that proxy has modified some web site's certificate. but command line also use the proxy, and from issuer name, I can find that both API and command line get the same issuer name that is modified by proxy.

Comment: But the proxy might introduce different public key, serial number, lifetime etc. All these parameters are put into the hash.

Comment: It may be correct that proxy introduce different public key. But my biggest confusion is that why openssl command line can get same public key as browser, my program get another public key, I think proxy should not treat them different. I want to get same public key same as openssl command line.

Comment: Please export the certificate from the browser and the certificate you get from openssl as a file and compare them. The fingerprint should only differ if the certificates differ.